# String has box like value which is not able to parse by java

Tags: java, string, hex

I am having problem to read file which has box in one place, when you see that box in hex mode it display as `00 01` i don`t know how to remove this character. and another problem is, in same file. some of the records has double quote inside double quote see the below string.

```
input one- "i am good but " some time i get values " 
input one- "i am good but " some "time i" get values " 


Output - "i am good but  some time i  get values "
```

Comment: you might have to save your file as per the encoding required for that box like character.

Comment: file has ASCII encoding

Comment: i tried "windows-1252", "USA-ASCII", "ISO-8859-15" non of them is able to read beyond problematic string.

Comment: Can you explain your issue with the double quotes further? Both example lines include them. Did you want them replaced with something else?